# Alternative to import Layer from 'ol/layer/Layer'

Tags: openlayers

I'm trying to replicate this open layers example:

https://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/mapbox-layer.html

However I want to use the downloaded full ol v5.3.0 release library. So far this has worked, where examples use:

```
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({});
```

I can just use:

```
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({});
```

However I'm unable to replicate the following using the above method:

```
import Layer from 'ol/layer/Layer';
var mbLayer = new Layer({})
```

I tried using:

```
var mbLayer = new ol.layer.Layer({
```

Which throws up an error:

```
ol.layer.Layer is not a constructor
```

Is it possible to create a new mapboxgl layer in openlayers, using this method?

Comment: OpenLayers 5 examples are in the "latest" directory path.  The "master" directory is used for the development version OpenLayers 6 beta.  To use OpenLayers 6 specific code with a full build download it from https://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js The corresponding css is at https://openlayers.org/en/master/css/ol.css  To minimise code changes you can replace the imports e.g. `import Layer from 'ol/layer/Layer';` becomes `var Layer = ol.layer.Layer;`

Comment: Thanks again Mike :) The link to OpenLayers 6 solved the problem.